# how to sum to specific items combined

Tags: google-sheets

looking for some assitance, how can i get the sum of specific multiple items combined

for example, i have a cleaning business, if on column a i have A1- WEEKLY A2-MONTH A3-On Call A4-Bi WK  clients are on column B, AND COST that i would be summing would be on column D,,

what is the formula if i want to sum how much for clients with a WEEKLY PLAN,

what is the formula to sum multiple plans at once, sum for weekly and Monthly together,,

Answer (score 0):

For monthly and weekly you can try this formula:

```
=Query(A1:D, "select A,sum(D) where A ='WEEKLY' or A = 'MONTH' group by A label A 'plan', sum(D) 'cost sum'",0)
```

Place it in a cell outside the `A1:D` range

**note**: *I may not have correctly interpreted your words, so in case attach an example file with the arrangement of the columns and the result you would like.*